# checkbox focus checked not fire

Tags: angular, typescript

I've a checkbox when it checked the events are not firing. [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8-reactive-form-validation-wycgqy?file=app/app.component.html) demo code. I want checkbox firing events without click on it. So I'm using button to trigger event

**HTML**

```
<div class="card m-3">
    <div class="card-body">
        <form [formGroup]="registerForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
            <div class="form-row">
                
                <div class="form-group col-5">
                    <label>First Name</label>
                    <input type="text" formControlName="firstName" class="form-control" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.firstName.errors }" />
                    <div *ngIf="submitted && f.firstName.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                        <div *ngIf="f.firstName.errors.required">First Name is required</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-5">
                    <label>Last Name</label>
                    <input type="text" formControlName="lastName" class="form-control" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.lastName.errors }" />
                    <div *ngIf="submitted && f.lastName.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                        <div *ngIf="f.lastName.errors.required">Last Name is required</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            
            <div class="form-group form-check">
                <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" [(ngModel)]="test" (focus)="eventCheck(registerForm.valid,$event)"
                [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"/>
                <label for="acceptTerms" class="form-check-label">Accept</label>
                <div *ngIf="submitted && f.acceptTerms.errors" class="invalid-feedback">Accept Ts & Cs is required</div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="text-center">
<button class="btn btn-primary mr-1" (click)="focusCheckbox()">Tick Checkbox</button>
</div>
```

**ts**

```
focusCheckbox() {
   this.test = true;
 }
eventCheck(v: boolean ,event){
  console.log(event.target.checked);
  console.log(v);
}
```

Comment: use (change) instead of (focus)

Comment: I've use (change) but it not working

Comment: it's working fine in your code

Comment: try you click button.., it not fire events

Comment: Okay but what you need to do on focus?? you need to show error message?

Comment: I want when user return it no need to checked it again. That why I use button as a simulation

Comment: Use ```focusout``` or ```blur``` event

Comment: Since you already have 'acceptTerms' in form controls, why not just control the checkbox value through Validator.requiredTrue?

Answer (score 0):

Use `blur` or `focusout` event.

Change from

`<input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" [(ngModel)]="test" (focus)="eventCheck(registerForm.valid,$event)"`

To :

```
  <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" [(ngModel)]="test" (blur)="eventCheck(registerForm.valid,$event)"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer... but it not working